# Two solutions for the LRU cache problem: why is one faster than the other?

Tags: c#, performance

I submitted a solution to leetcode's LRU cache problem and it ranked in the 33% as far as runtime. I then saw that the submission that was 98% faster than the rest was almost identical to mine with minor differences. Biggest difference I noticed was that instead of using a dictionary and linkedlist of ints, they used a user-defined struct. I do not understand why that makes a difference in performance. thanks!

#### My solution:

```
public class LRUCache 
{
    Dictionary<int,int> LRUDict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    LinkedList<int> keys = new LinkedList<int>();
    int capacity = 0;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int Get(int key) {
        int retval = -1;
        int entry;
        if (LRUDict.TryGetValue(key,out entry))
        {
            retval = entry;
            keys.Remove(key);
            keys.AddLast(key);
        }
        return retval;
    }

    public void Put(int key, int value) {
        //case 1: exists, no need to increment count and check capacity, just change value and move up
        if (LRUDict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            keys.Remove(key);
            keys.AddLast(key);
        }
        //case 2: does not exist, need to add new entry, may need to kick out oldest one
        else
        {
            keys.AddLast(key);
            if (keys.Count > capacity)
            {
                int LRUKey = keys.First.Value;
                keys.RemoveFirst();
                LRUDict.Remove(LRUKey);
            }
        }
        LRUDict[key] =value;
    }
}
```

#### The faster solution:

```
public class LRUCache {

    struct Cache {
        public int Key { get;set; }
        public int Val { get;set; }
    }

    private int _capacity;
    private LinkedList<Cache> _cache = new LinkedList<Cache>();
    private Dictionary<int, LinkedListNode<Cache>> _keys = new Dictionary<int, LinkedListNode<Cache>>();

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int Get(int key) {

        if (_keys.TryGetValue(key, out var node)) {

            _cache.Remove(node);
            _cache.AddLast(node);

            return node.Value.Val;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void Put(int key, int value) {

        LinkedListNode<Cache> n;
        var containsKey = _keys.TryGetValue(key, out n);
        if (_cache.Count >= _capacity && !containsKey) {
            var invalidNode = _cache.First;
            _cache.RemoveFirst();
            _keys.Remove(invalidNode.Value.Key);
        }

        if (containsKey) {

            _cache.Remove(n);

        } 

        var cache = new Cache { Key = key, Val = value };
        var node = new LinkedListNode<Cache>(cache);
        _cache.AddLast(node);
        _keys[key] = node;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This question seems to be concerned with performance and if so may be better asked on another Stack Exchange site one dedicated to _code review_.  Be sure to read the relevant FAQ before posting. Good luck

Comment: Could you provide code that benchmarks your implementation? Would help everyone to set up a solution to test it

Comment: I agree with Mickey, there's also a lot of intricacies about structs that will yield a result here and is probably too broad to be one stack overflow question. If you don't know what a struct is check it out, and for linked lists look up Bjornes talk on why they're so slow. It's enlightening

Comment: Thanks guys for the helpful advice! I know what a struct is, and I am using a linked list myself. I believe user2864740 may be up to something here. Thanks all :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to the code review Q&A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution is faster because it removes a LinkedListNode, which can be done in O(1). The first solution removes a value, which requires searching the linked list or O(n) time.

As such, the first solution will scale very poorly with more items.

Look at the exact Remove method overloads used in both cases - and the corresponding documentation.

- [LinkedList.Remove(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_LinkedList_1_Remove__0_) - used in first solution

  > Removes the first occurrence of the specified value.. This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation..
- [LinkedList.Remove(LinkedListNode<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_LinkedList_1_Remove_System_Collections_Generic_LinkedListNode__0__) - used in second solution

  > Removes the specified node.. This method is an O(1) operation.

Comment: That is it, thanks a lot!!